# CLLocationManager not requesting permission from user

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am working on an app in Swift which has to get the GPS coordinates of the user. I have added the keys (NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription) to info.pList like so:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location is required to find your coordinates</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location is required to find your coordinates</string>
```

I have also added the CoreLocation.framework and requested authorisation in the viewDidLoad method:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var locManager = CLLocationManager()

    locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    locManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse){

            var currentLocation = locManager.location
            longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
            latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
            textBox.text = longitude.description + latitude.description

    }
}
```

The problem is, as it says in the title, that the user is not prompted for permission so the location is never updated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried following Apple's instructions to the letter yet? The "Requesting Permission to Use Location Services" section of the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) has a different flow to what you've used, specifically that you should check the status before asking for authorisation, and you should set a delegate. Might not fix your problem, but it's worth trying to do it their way first if you've not done so yet.

Comment: Try this in viewDidAppear -:         locManager = CLLocationManager()
        locManager.delegate = self
        locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        locManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add this line

locManager.delegate = self;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

locManager.delegate = self;
locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

locManager.startUpdatingLocation()

if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse){

        var currentLocation = locManager.location
        longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
        latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        textBox.text = longitude.description + latitude.description

}
```

than in your class add CLLocationManagerDelegate
example

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

finally change the scope of

```
var locManager = CLLocationManager()
```

for example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,CLLocationManagerDelegate{
  var locManager = CLLocationManager()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your locManager as a property of the ViewController,not as a local variable.

```
class YourViewController {
    var locManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        locManager = CLLocationManager()
        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        ...
    }
}
```